# Mysql inline query returns different result than query with session variable

Tags: mysql

I have a table "firstname"

```
+----+-------+
| id |  name |
+----+-------+
| 1  |  Sam  |
| 2  |  Tom  |
| 3  | David | 
| 4  |  Bob  | 
+----+-------+
```

Now I just want to enforce MySql to give me a random name each time I querying. So to do this I perform:

```sql
select name 
from firstname 
where id = CEIL((select count(*) from firstname) * rand());
```

and this query from time to time returns from zero to three results. But if I set a session variable with containing the earlier calculated id, then it works fine

```sql
set @x = CEIL((select count(*) from firstname) * rand());

select name 
from firstname 
where id = @x;
```

Why is this happening? How to do the inline query without session variable that works fine ?

Tested on '5.6.25' and '5.6.51'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name 
from firstname 
JOIN (SELECT CEIL((select count(*) from firstname) * rand()) id) id USING (id);
```

You must calculate needed randon `id` once and apply it to all the rows whereas in your query it is calculated and applied for each separate row with different result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But please can you explain why it is needed? In my inline query I calculated it once also. Why do I need a separated query? You have done the same like I did with session variable by making Join and additional select. Why do I need a separated query. Why I cannot calculate this in one single select. Thank you

Comment: *In my inline query I calculated it once also.* No. WHERE is tested for each separate row. And the expression is calculated (and RAND() is called for this calculation, giving new value) for each separate testing, i.e. for each row.